# Collecting success and total from incomplete binary groups in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Lets say I have the following

```
>blob

id  group  growth
1     A      1
2     A      1
3     B      0
4     B      1
5     B      0
6     C      0
7     C      0
8     C      0
```

I would like to eventually pull out success out of total data. I have gone this far

```
blob %>% 
  group_by(group,growth) %>% 
  tally() 

  group  growth  n
     A      1    2
     B      0    2
     B      1    1
     C      0    3
```

I would like to have something like

```
  group  success  total
     A      2      2
     B      1      3
     C      0      3
```

I have also tried

```
sales %>% 
  group_by(group,growth) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  summarise(fail= n[factor(growth)==1],total = sum(n))
```

but I get an error because not all growths are equal to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n()` is a function from `dplyr` to count the number. If we `group_by` the group, we can use `n()` to count the number of rows and also use `sum` to add up the success number.

```
library(dplyr)
dt2 <- dt %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(success = sum(growth), n = n())
```

#### Data Preparation

```
dt <- read.table(text = "id  group  growth
1     A      1
2     A      1
3     B      0
4     B      1
5     B      0
6     C      0
7     C      0
8     C      0",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: For anyone interested, the data.table analogue is `library(data.table); setDT(dt)[, .(.N, succ = sum(growth)), by=group]`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example with `data.table`

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df1)

df1[, .(success = sum(growth), total = .N), by=group]

   group success total
1:     A       2     2
2:     B       1     3
3:     C       0     3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  a=Map(tapply,list(dt$growth),list(dt$group),c(sum,length))
 `names<-`(do.call(cbind.data.frame,a),c("Successes","Totals"))
    Successes Totals
  A         2      2
  B         1      3
  C         0      3
```

You can use a mapply function instead of a map:

```
  mapply(tapply,list(dt$growth),list(dt$group),c(sum,length))
    [,1] [,2]
 A    2    2
 B    1    3
 C    0    3
```

Then you can decide to give the names you want to the specific columns. (Please change the class of the object from matrix to a dataframe).